# Trying to create a simple bash function but get the syntax error near unexpected token `(' error

Tags: bash, terminal

I'm trying to modify my .bash_profile which currently looks like:

```
alias kx="kubectx"
gcreds () {
gcloud container clusters get-credentials $1 --zone $2;
}
```

however when i try to :wq and source .bash_profile (in a mac os x terminal) i get the following error message:

```
bash: .bash_profile: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: .bash_profile: line 14: `gcreds (){'
```

a colleague also tested the same (in an iterm terminal) and was able to run the function with no errors

any ideas what i could be doing wrong?

Comment: You probably want to [double-quote the positional parameters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618).

Answer (score 1):

Hypothesis: In your (but not in your colleague's) shell `gcreds` is an *alias* defined before the troublesome line is parsed.

Alias expansion happens early and it's purely textual (i.e. `gcreds` *string* gets replaced by some *string*, no logic there). Your definition of the function becomes invalid, probably because `()` is not after the very first word. E.g. if `gcreds` was replaced by `gcreds --something` then it would be:

```
gcreds --something () { …
```

which is not a syntactically valid definition of a function. But it may be `gcreds` gets replaced by something else:

```
something-else-than-gcreds whatever and more () { …
```

It doesn't matter what the replacement is. The fact `()` is now in the wrong place matters.

In Bash you can run `type gcreds` to see what `gcreds` really is. Also try `type -a gcreds` (and `help type` to learn what `-a` does).

You can define a function in an alternative way, without `()`:

```
function gcreds { …
```

This syntax is [not portable](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism). I understand you're going to use it inside `~/.bash_profile` which is a Bash-specific file, so it's OK.

Now the first word is `function`. I assume it's not aliased and it's interpreted as a keyword (check `type function`). If so, the `gcreds` alias is not expanded when the definition is parsed, it cannot break the definition. This way you can define a function named `gcreds`, even if there's already a `gcreds` alias.

Suppose you manage to define `gcreds` alias and `gcreds` function. Now if you run `gcreds foo bar` and your alias replaces `gcreds` with `gcreds …` then the alias will be expanded first, the function will be executed later. But if your alias replaces `gcreds` with `something-else-than-gcreds …` then the alias will be expanded first, the function won't matter (a function named `something-else-than-gcreds` would mater, if any).

You probably don't need an alias *and* a function with the same name. Pick one. If you do need them both, define the function first, the alias later; or use the keyword `function` as shown above.